Windows Scheduler Task missed start task rejected mechanism
Can someone explain to me the mechanism of how the Windows Scheduler Task checks for a "missed task start rejected"? This morning, when I checked the scheduler task history, I saw a warning stating "Missed task start rejected."

Here are the specific task settings:

Running on a Windows Azure virtual machine that is automatically
started at 8 AM and shut down at 10 PM (on weekdays from Monday to
Friday).
The task is scheduled to run daily at 9 PM every day.
"Allow task to be run on demand" is enabled.
"Run task as soon as possible after a scheduled start is missed" is disabled.
"If the task fails, restart every..." is disabled.

I want to avoid seeing that warning without actually running my task. If possible, please provide me with official documentation as that would be very helpful.
Thank you very much for your help.
